# Cant get counter when counting key words in a source code working right

Tags: python

I cant get my counter working right, its supposed to count two whiles when two whiles are typed but its only counting one, please help. , here are the instructions.

Write a program that reads in a Python source code as a one-line text and counts the occurrence of each keyword in the file. Display the keyword and count in ascending order on keywords.

```
phrase = input('Enter Python source code:')
phrase1 = set(phrase.split(' '))
phrase1 = list(phrase1)
phrase1.sort()
counter = 0
keywords = {"and", "del", "from", "not", "while",
                "as", "elif", "global", "or", "with",
                "assert", "else", "if", "pass", "yield",
                "break", "except", "import", "print",
                "class", "exec", "in", "raise",
                "continue", "finally", "is", "return",
                "def", "for", "lambda", "try"}
keywords = tuple(keywords)
phrase1 = tuple(phrase1)
dict1 = {}
for x in keywords:
    dict1 = dict1.fromkeys(keywords, counter)
for x in phrase1:
    if x in dict1:
        dict1[x] += 1
        print(x, ':', dict1[x])
```

Comment: Why do you need the `for x in keywords:` loop? You keep setting `dict1` to the same dictionary each time.

Comment: Didnt realize that, thanks, i cant get the counter working right though, help please?

Comment: You're getting rid of duplicates by doing `set(phrase.split(' '))`

Comment: How do I seperate each word and still keep the duplicates

Comment: Just use `split` without converting it to a set.

Comment: Thank you, now its printing while twice, output - while; 1, while:2

Comment: How do i get it to just print once with total count

Comment: Take the print out of the loop.

Comment: Why did you put it in the loop in the first place if you didn't want it to print multiple times?

Comment: It worked, but its only printing one keywords, not all of the ones typed

Comment: Im still a student learning python in college

Comment: Use `print(dict1)`